# Using Alembic in unit testing a SQLAlchemy app?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, integration-testing, alembic

I have and ORM app that uses SQLAlchemy, Alembic for migration and Pytest for testing. In my testing, I have a database as a fixture. It used to be, before I used migrations, that I dropped all the tables and recreated them for each testing session.

Now that I am using migrations, I want to use Alembic in creating my fixtures too because I believe that mimics a production environment more closely.(Is that a good rationale?)

One way to do it is to `downgrade()` all the way down and `upgrade()` up each time. I don't really like this. I might be wrong.

Another would be to `drop_all()` and `create_all()` for unit tests, and just write another test that stamps the database with head and tests an `upgrade` and `downgrade`.

Is there another good/standard way to integrate migrations with fixtures so I do not have to use `drop_tables`?

Or is there a way to, after `drop_tables` stamp the db as "tail" or empty? without explicitly using the migration hash for revision 0, cause that creates dependencies, something like `alembic downgrade -1` that will make it go back to year 0. Thank you.

Comment: I think technically, this would qualify as an integration test.  It might help some searches to refer to it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend starting a temporary database instance each time, e.g. with [`testing.mysqld`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testing.mysqld) or [`testing.postgresql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testing.postgresql). The advantage of this approach is that you're guaranteed to start fresh each time; the success of your tests will not depend on external factors. The downside is the extra handful of seconds that it takes to start the instance.

If you insist on using an existing database instance, you can, like you said, use `create_all()` + `alembic stamp head`. However, instead of doing `drop_all()`, simply drop the entire database (or schema, in the case of PostgreSQL) and recreate it.

If you insist on using `drop_all()`, you can drop the `alembic_version` table to tell alembic that the current version is "tail".

Comment: Thank you. The problem with `testing.psql` was that it requires psql to start a temp instance, my environment is containerized and my db is in another container, and I do not have psql in my orm container. I did not want to pull a pg into it as well so I ended up stamping tails

Comment: For future references: `alembic downgrade base`
http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#downgrading

Comment: Just passing by. testing.postgresql hasn't been updated since 2016. https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/ is still maintained.